# How to setup Splunk Universal Forwarder on Windows Azure web role?

Tags: windows, azure-web-roles, splunk

What is the best way(cost effective) to setup Splunk Universal Forwarder on a Windows Azure web role instance?

The download page on [Splunk Website](http://www.splunk.com/download/universalforwarder) has an installer for Windows, but not sure how could we run in to install and configure on every deployment to Windows Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure Startup task for this. Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Build a powershell script which will install Splunk Universal Forwarder 
   (reference - http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.0.3/Forwarding/DeployaWindowsdfviathecommandline)
2. Add a startup task to your web role. This startup task can be a batch file that will trigger the above powershell. (Reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180155.aspx)

Package and deploy the cloud service. Once the status of the Web role becomes Ready, you can RDP and verify the universal forwarder installation.

Comment: Note that this may make sense to only do on a worker role, not a web role. To use a forwarder to collect data from a web role, it would be better to write to blob/table/queues and have Splunk pick it up from there using one of the available apps written for this purpose.

But the steps as written ought to work on a worker role!